# Example of ordinals $a,b,c$ such that $(a + b) \cdot c \neq a\cdot c + b\cdot c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I know that $c\cdot(a +b)=c\cdot a+c\cdot b$, but I don't see the counterexample to the hypothesized property in the question.

Comment: $(1+1)\cdot\omega\ne1\cdot\omega+1\cdot\omega$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, we have that $(\omega_0+1)\cdot\omega_0$ is the supremum of $\{(\omega_0+1)\cdot n\mid n\text{ is finite}\}$. This supremum is $\omega_0^2$, not $\omega_0^2+\omega_0$.

Comment: $(1+1)\cdot\omega$ was too simple?

Comment: @bof It wasn't the first I thought of. I started with squaring $\omega+1$ because I knew that didn't work as "expected".